# Capitalisation when talking about a proper noun

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

So when I write a sentence like for example:

> The word europe originated from ...

should the word be capitalised or not? It seems logical not to capitalise because in this sense it's not talking about the continent *Europe* but just the word.

Comment: You always capitalize proper nouns, even when you're referencing the word rather than what it names. It should also be quoted or italic.

Comment: The word is Europe, not europe. Just like NaCl is NaCl. Of course, sometimes it's not so easy: china and China are different. iPhones are the best selling smartphones: 'iPhone' needs the lowercase _i_ even if someone decides to start a sentence with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Barmar pointed out, all proper nouns should *always* be capitalized, the context doesn't matter.

This is backed up by [Your Dictionary.com](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalizing-proper-nouns.html#:%7E:text=The%20basic%20rule%20for%20capitalizing,words%20needs%20to%20be%20capitalized.):

> The basic rule for capitalizing proper nouns is that the first letter of a proper noun should be capitalized no matter where it appears in a sentence or how it is being used.

This rule makes sense. It's still the same word with the same rules, no matter what words surround it.

Also, as @Barmar mentioned, *Europe* would also be italicized or put into quotation (less of a hard rule, but you should nonetheless follow it).